# How to login to liferay website using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, liferay, performance-testing, http-authentication

I am facing one problem that i am unable to login to the liferay website using JMeter.

The problem i know already but don't know how to hanmdle it.

I get to know that "p_auth" token is requried to access the sub pages, but here i am facing an issue in which i don't even able to acccess the login page itself if run the script second time.

My concerns:

- how to check "p_auth" token parameter for login page (i.e without login)

Please help me to solve the problem.

**Note:** i tried to extract the "p_auth" token , but i am unable to see any "p_auth" token for login page itself(i.e without login.. just a login page(get api))

Answer (score 2):

Your test plan need to look like:

- Open Login Page - [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request

  - Extract `p_auth` dynamic parameter value using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
- Perform the login - [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request where you need to provide your credentials and the `p_auth` token value from the previous request

You won't be able to "see" the token in the page, it's hidden in the page source so you will need to use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or JMeter's [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in order to "see" the token value.

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter) to your test plan as missing CSRF token is not the only thing which can stop you from logging in.